# Display Message On Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that I want a message to pop up on if certain conditions are met.  How do I connect this to the asp code.

```
if (ParentLoadManager.Fuel.ID == 2)
        {
            string mytext = Phrases.NAT_GAS_WELDER;

        }
```

Here is the front end:

```
 <div class="formrow">
   <div class="label1">
     &nbsp;
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvWelderError" runat="server" 
      ValidationGroup="save" Display="Dynamic" meta:resourcekey="cvWelderError" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a control on the client (front end), for example a label, then set the correct property to the string mytext.

Client

```
<div class="formrow">
   <div class="label1">
     <asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server" />
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvWelderError" runat="server" 
      ValidationGroup="save" Display="Dynamic" meta:resourcekey="cvWelderError" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

Server

```
if (ParentLoadManager.Fuel.ID == 2) {
     myLabel.Text = Phrases.NAT_GAS_WELDER;
}
```

Comment: Hey Shaun, what is the purpose of the "Me" on the server-side code?

Comment: Sorry, mixed in a bit of VB.NET in there.

Answer (score 0):

So I learned that the validation was completely unnecessary.  Here is what I did:

```
<div class="formrow">
  <div class="label1">
    <asp:label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
  </div>
<div>
```